# How to insert drm into html file programatically?

Tags: java, html, jsp, drm

Here i am describing my question in detail:-

1. Is there any way to insert drm into html programmatically?
2. Secondly after inserting drm the file shouldn't be be allowed to print and its content shouldn't be copied or pasted.
3. And lastly I don't want html user having permission to remove that code(drm). Is there any way to restrict the user from editing  the file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No way to do that in a sensible way. HTML is text when its transferred over a network, so anyone can retrieve the text and avoid any "DRM" that it contains.

Why do you think you even need to protect your HTML?

Comment: I need it for ebook in html format

Comment: Your requirements prevent it from being html. Formats such as `epub` have (limited) DRM capabilities, but html can't have those.